how do i update an object in flutter?
I am trying to update an object in flutter and what i have is a grid view objects and trying to update the passed object to a details page but it won't update what am i doing wrong?
and I get this err
Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: -1
this is my details page:
            isEditing.editData
                ? MyTextField(
                    controller: titleController,
                    hintText: 'Title',
                    obscureText: false,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      titleController.text = value;
                    },
                  )
                : Text(title),
            isEditing.editData
                ? MyTextField(
                    controller: authorController,
                    hintText: 'Author',
                    obscureText: false,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      authorController.text = value;
                    },
                  )
                : Text(author),
            isEditing.editData
                ? MyTextField(
                    controller: publisherController,
                    hintText: 'Publisher',
                    obscureText: false,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      publisherController.text = value;
                    },
                  )
                : Text(publisher),
            isEditing.editData
                ? MyTextField(
                    controller: copywriteController,
                    hintText: 'Copywrite',
                    obscureText: false,
                  )
                : Text(copywrite),
            isEditing.editData
                ? MyTextField(
                    controller: isbnController,
                    hintText: 'Isbn #',
                    obscureText: false,
                  )
                : Text(isbn),
            isEditing.editData
                ? DropdownButton<String>(
                    // Initial Value
                    value: selectedIo,

                    // Down Arrow Icon
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

                    // Array list of items
                    items: io.map((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      selectedIo = newValue!;
                    },
                  )
                : Text(book.io),
            isEditing.editData
                ? DropdownButton<String>(
                    // Initial Value
                    value: selectedWho,

                    // Down Arrow Icon
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

                    // Array list of items
                    items: who.map((String items) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: selectedWho,
                        child: Text(items),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    // After selecting the desired option,it will
                    // change button value to selected value
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      selectedWho = newValue!;
                    },
                  )
                : Text(book.who),
            isEditing.editData
                ? DropdownButton<String>(
                    // Initial Value
                    value: selectedLost,

                    // Down Arrow Icon
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

                    // Array list of items
                    items: lost.map((String items) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: items,
                        child: Text(items),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    // After selecting the desired option,it will
                    // change button value to selected value
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      selectedLost = newValue!;
                    },
                  )
                : Text(book.lost.toString()),

                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ref.read(editProvider.notifier).toggleEditting();
                    final updatedBook = Book(
                      id: id,
                      title: titleController.text,
                      author: author,
                      publisher: publisher,
                      copywrite: copywrite,
                      isbn: isbn,
                      io: selectedIo.toString(),
                      who: selectedWho.toString(),
                      lost: selectedLost.toString(),
                      imgPath: book.imgPath,
                    );
                    BookList().updateBook(updatedBook: updatedBook);
                  },

if you need more info please let me know
